# Copy rows to new sheet if condition is met (with VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy rows from master table sheet to different sheets based on the value of the cell in the column:

The column "AL" contains several values (validation list) for example `dog`, `cat`, `giraffe`, I'd like to automatically open new sheet for every value and copy the relevant rows to the new sheet. (the new sheets must have the name of the value).

In addition when a new data is added, I need the new rows to be added to the correct sheet.

```
Sub Copy_Data()
Dim r As Range, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Dim v As Variant, s As String, LastRow1 As Long
Dim src As Worksheet
Set src = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = src.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AL").End(xlUp).Row
'Change these to your strings to copy
s = "dog,cat,fish,giraffe"
v = Split(s, ",")
For Each r In src.Range("AL1:AL" & LastRow)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(CStr(r.Value), v, 0)) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Sheets(CStr(r.Value))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = CStr(r.Value)
            LastRow1 = Sheets(CStr(r.Value)).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AL").End(xlUp).Row
            src.Rows(r.Row).Copy Sheets(CStr(r.Value)).Cells(LastRow1 + 1, 1)
            Set ws = Nothing
        Else
            LastRow1 = Sheets(CStr(r.Value)).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "Al").End(xlUp).Row
            src.Rows(r.Row).Copy Sheets(CStr(r.Value)).Cells(LastRow1 + 1, 1)
            Set ws = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: Plese, show your code and specify your trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Because this is not a free code writing service you will need to show (your code) what you already have tried. Read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) to understand how a good question should look like, and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).